# HTTP request doesn't hit WEB API 2 controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to secure a web API 2 with MSAL.
My authentication client side works and I get a valid token (verified with jwt.io).

I have a Web API 2 configured as such :

The WebAPI Config :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.All;
   config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    config.EnableCors();
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
}
```

My Startup.Auth.cs looks like this:

```
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string clientId = "the_client_id";

        var tokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
        {
            ValidAudience = clientId,
            ValidateIssuer = false
        };
        Debug.WriteLine("Client ID = " + tokenValidationParameters.ValidAudience);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AccessTokenFormat = new Microsoft.Owin.Security.Jwt.JwtFormat(tokenValidationParameters, new OpenIdConnectCachingSecurityTokenProvider("https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration"))
        });
    }
```

And a simple controller :

```
[Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class BundlesController : ApiController
{
    private APIContext db = new APIContext();

    // GET: api/Bundles
    public IQueryable<Bundles> GetBundles()
    {
        Claim subject = ClaimsPrincipal.Current.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier);
        db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
        return db.Bundles.Include(x => x.Products.Select(y => y.Defects));
    }
```

Before adding the [Authorize] attributes, the API worked like a charm and returned correctly the data.

If I set a breakpoint in the GET function from the controller, it won't get hit and I'll get a 401 : Authorization has been denied for this request.
I'm fairly sure I registered my app correctly in apps.dev.microsoft.com.

I don't understand at what point my API is blocking the calls.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated !

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, sorry for the disturbance !

My issue was that I was calling from the App the token method that way:

```
App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { premissionScopes });
```

When I should have done

```
App.IdentityClientApp.AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { Constants.ApplicationID });
```

So yeah, you're supposed to get the first token with the application ID and then give the scopes to the silent token acquiring method once you have the token.

Answer (score 2):

I　just tested your code both on my local and Azure Web App. All worked fine. The API could be reached after adding [Authorize] attributes.

> My authentication client side works and I get a valid token (verified with jwt.io).

Token will expired depends on the exp property of JWT. By default, it will expired in 60 min. Try to re-generate the token and use it to access your Web API.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I call AcquireTokenSilentAsync before every API call.
If I understand right, I'm supposed to get a token and extend the expiration date. Anyway, for test purposes, I log in everytime so the expiration should not be an issue.

Comment: I was getting the token that way :
AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { "User.Read" }) and changed it to AcquireTokenAsync(new String[] { applicationID })
It seems to work. Do you think the issue comes from here ?

Comment: Yes. That is the reason. According to the official sample, applicationID is required.

Comment: Since your issue is solved, I suggest you close your thread by mark helpful replies as answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi can you please try adding supports credentials: true to your cors?.
So your EnableCors attribute would look something like this

```
 EnableCors [origin:*,headers:*,methods:*,supportsCredentials:true]
```

Hope this helps.

Thanks,
Bhadhri